# Why can we not submit apps written in Swift before iOS 8 is released?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

Swift can be used for writing applications that run on iOS 7 and prior or Mac OS X 10.9 and prior. Why do we have to wait with submitting applications to App Store until fall when iOS 8 and Mac OS X 10.10 is released?

Learning Swift today and using it in 4-5 months is inefficient. Also writing new code in Objective-C instead of Swift is counterproductive when Swift will be probably the future of Apple platforms.

Comment: [Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)

Comment: I found this question and answer useful. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 17):

Probably due to the fact that you need Xcode 6, which is still in beta and won't be ready before iOS 8 / Yosemite ships.

Comment: You can download Xcode 6 today and run it on Maverick and compile Swift application with it that targets iOS 7 or Mac OS X 10.9. So I don't understand it.

Comment: Submitting apps to the store with beta compilers is never a good idea (and afaik never allowed)

Comment: @Catfish_Man That's a great point.

Comment: and as we've seen with the 3rd beta, the language is still changing and breaking, currently image asset libraries won't compile to iOS 7.. it's not quite ready for primetime...